# What's wrong in this mapping code?

Tags: solidity, solc

Could someone please point out what is wrong in this code? It seems that when I call the registerClient() function, it succeeds and returns TRUE. But when I call the getRegisteredClients() method, it always returns 0!!

```
struct RegisteredCandidate {
    bytes32 ownerID;
    address clientAddress;
}

mapping( bytes32=> RegisteredCandidate) registeredCandidates;
bytes32[] registeredClients; //an array of clients to keep track of numbers

//Just a modifier to restrict calls
modifier ifIssuer() {
            if (issuer != msg.sender){
                  revert();
              }
              else {
                _;
     }
    }

function registerClient(bytes32 _clientID) public returns (bool) {

      //if the clientID is not already present in the map
      if(registeredCandidates[_clientID].ownerID != _clientID) {

          registeredCandidates[_clientID].ownerID = _clientID;
          registeredCandidates[_clientID].clientAddress = msg.sender;
          registeredClients.push(_clientID); //updating the counter array
          return true;
      }

      return false;
  }

    function getRegisteredClients() constant returns (uint) {
        registeredClients.length;

    }
```

Thanks for any help on this.

One more question to ask: is there a better way to form the same logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are missing "return" in getRegisteredClients()

Comment: Ohh...that was dumb! Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you didn't add `return` keyword in your `getRegisteredClients` method.

```
function getRegisteredClients() constant returns (uint) {
   return registeredClients.length;
}
```

Comment: Ohh...that was dumb! Thanks a lot for pointing it out.